# Update table a from table b where (conditions)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Evening all,

Actually, it's night.  About 11pm.  My brain is shutting down and I need a bit of help so I can finish and go home :)

I have two tables - table a and table b.
I need to update a field in table a with the value from a field in table b when two other fields match.  The tables don't have a unique id for each record :(

Basically, I want to do this:

```
update a
set importantField = 
(select b.importantfield
from b
where a.matchfield = b.matchfield
and a.matchfield2 = b.matchfield2
)
where a.matchfield = b.matchfield
and a.matchfield2 = b.matchfield2
```

Or at least... I think that's what I want to do...

Can someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this via a join in the update:

```
Update a
Set a.importantField = b.importantField
From a Join b 
  On a.matchfield = b.matchfield
  And a.matchfield2 = b.matchfield2
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius.
...and I really am tired not to think of doing a join...
I can now go home and it's all thanks to you!  Give yourself a pat on the back :D

Comment: @Cosmic: Glad it works for you...I had to double check this worked, spent too much time inside LINQ lately :)

Comment: I think you need to set an alias for `a` table in order for this to work, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
   SET importantField = (SELECT b.importantfield
                           FROM TABLE_B b
                          WHERE b.matchfield = matchfield
                            AND b.matchfield2 = matchfield2)
```

SQL Server doesn't support table aliases on the table being updated, but the above is a correlated query - those fields without the table alias `b` attached will serve values from `TABLE_A` because it doesn't have an alias.

The only issue beyond that is if there are multiple `b.importantfield` values for records with the matching records to TABLE_A. Use:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
   SET importantField = (SELECT TOP 1 
                                b.importantfield
                           FROM TABLE_B b
                          WHERE b.matchfield = matchfield
                            AND b.matchfield2 = matchfield2)
```

..but you should use an `ORDER BY` as well or you'll get any random `b.importantfield` value.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write me an answer.  I didn't use your solution in the end but I want to thank you for it anyway.  So thank you :)

Comment: Can we somehow make that update only not null results from right side of equation? I mean update only if b.importantfield is not null