# MySQL update from one table to another with condition not working?

Tags: mysql, join

I have tried a solution that seems to work for someone else on this question:

[Update table a from table b where (conditions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158681/update-table-a-from-table-b-where-conditions)
I can not seem to get it working, MySql gives me a syntax error.

I have two tables, and I need to update a column in one table to the value of another column where an id matches in both tables.

> UPDATE video_data SET video_data.date_timestamp = video.date_timestamp FROM video_data JOIN video ON video_data.video_id = video.video_id

I am not sure what the issue is with my syntax. I am quite tired and maybe it is just my eyes playing with me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: looks fine to me...you semi-colon the end?

Comment: I am running it in phpmyadmin, I added the semi-colon to make sure, but same error:   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM video_data JOIN video ON video_data.video_id = video.video_id' at line 1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this syntax out:

```
UPDATE video_data, video 
SET video_data.date_timestamp = video.date_timestamp
WHERE  video_data.video_id = video.video_id
```

Comment: i have a feeling it's the guy who posted the wrong answer with no where condition. :(

Comment: This worked perfect, I updated 8,341,529 records in 50 seconds. I thought my original SQL was similar to this, but obviously I was wrong on that one as well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE video_data, video SET video_data.date_timestamp = video.date_timestamp
WHERE video_data.video_id = video.video_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE video_data SET date_timestamp = (SELECT video.date_timestamp FROM video WHERE  video.video_id = video_data.video_id)
```

Although the error in your actual query is simply that you missed a "SELECT"

```
UPDATE video_data SET video_data.date_timestamp = SELECT video.date_timestamp FROM video_data JOIN video ON video_data.video_id = video.video_id
```

But I don't think it is what you want it to be.