# How to insert rows in a column with data gotten from mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables: STD and SMS. What I need to do is to select from table STD the copy the result to an array then insert each element of the array to another table, SMS.

Here's my code:

```
$query=mysql_query("Select from STD WHEre <my conditions>");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query)
foreach($result as $value)
mysql_query("INSERT INTO SMS set SMS.column='$value'")
```

It is not updating the SMS table at all. Can someone here have a better idea or tell me what's wrong with the code? thanks.

Comment: is that pseudo code? because you dont select anything in your first query... and you would update every row in your SMS table

Comment: no, i'm sorry. I just ommited my conditions.

Answer (score 1):

try this, **but this will update all the values of the table like your actual query does**:

```
    $query=mysql_query("Update SMS set 
    SMS.column=(Select <column_name> from STD where <my conditions> limit 1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You about updating or inserting data? if You want to insert [user JW already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14962602/1880351), else you must set condition on Your update query.

```
$query=mysql_query("Select from STD WHEre <my conditions>");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query)
foreach($result as $value)
mysql_query("Update SMS set SMS.column='$value' where SMS.std_id = '{$value['id']}'"); /// fieldnames are my example, You must generate Your condition..
```

or You can use [update from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6935776/1880351)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in just one query, use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO SMS (col1, col2, ...., Coll3)
SELECT col1, col2, ...., Coll3
FROM STD
```

Comment: I can't. The array that I might produce may be in the value of hundreds.

Comment: you don't need array to store values on this.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're trying to get all rows from the `STD` table and insert them into the `SMS` table, and that the `SMS` table definition is the same as the `STD` one?

If so, this should work:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `STD` WHERE <my_conditions>');
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== FALSE) // Loop over all rows selected
{
  $columns = implode(', ', array_keys($row)); // returns string of column names e.g. "col1, col2, col3" etc.
  $values = "'" . implode("', '", array_values($row)) . "'"; // returns string of quoted values e.g. "'val1', 'val2', 'val3'"
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `SMS` ($columns) VALUES ($values)"); // inserts the row into the SMS database table
}
```