# update values in a column in one table from another on condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
UPDATE rates_master 
SET rates_master.interest_min=rates_master_live.interest_min
FROM rates_master
LEFT JOIN rates_master_live ON 
rates_master_live.bank_id = rates_master.bank_id
and rates_master.product_id =1
```

I want to fetch all values from rates_master_live tables interest_min column to rates_master interest_min for only product having id=1

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL update from one table to another with condition not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935741/mysql-update-from-one-table-to-another-with-condition-not-working)

Comment: Any error ....?

Answer (score 0):

No need for `LEFT JOIN`. Just use `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
UPDATE rates_master 
SET rates_master.interest_min=rates_master_live.interest_min
FROM rates_master
INNER JOIN rates_master_live ON 
rates_master_live.bank_id = rates_master.bank_id
WHERE rates_master.product_id =1
```

`LEFT JOIN` will return all the rows from the table `rates_master` even if they don't match the condition in the `on` clause. However, `INNER JOIN` will return only the rows that match the condition from both the tables.

Comment: This showing error message as follows `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM rates_master
INNER JOIN rates_master_live ON 
rates_master_live.bank_id = rates' at line 3`